# Send Html with ajax wrong Css structure

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

i´am trying to send with ajax an html site, but on the server side, the structure of the css is damaged.

My getInfo function return a variable with a html text how looks like this

```
<div id="Center">center<button style="margin-left: 109px; margin-top: -9px; position: absolute;">juhu</button></div>
```

this variable, i send with ajax to my php page:

```
$.ajax({
url:"createFile.php",
type:"post",
dataType:"text",
data:getInfo()
});
```

but on the server site(the php page) the value of the post variable is this:

```
<div id="Center">center<button absolute;\"="" position:="" -9px;="" margin-top:="" 109px;="" style="\&quot;margin-left:" xmlns="\&quot;http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\&quot;">juhu</button></div>
```

What is wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the backslash´s. I thing jquery add a backslash on every " " ".
The solution was the "stripslashes" function on the php server-site.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, this should work:

```
$.ajax({
url:"createFile.php",
type:"post",
dataType:"html",
processData:false,
data:getInfo()
});
```